# Eclipse: intellisense laggy, how to change functionality

Tags: android, eclipse

I've recently moved from VS to eclipse and am using the intellisense functionality.  I came across a tutorial a week ago telling me to add 'source' directories to the android sdk to improve the speed of intellisense.

Anyways i still find it a bit sluggish and i was curious if there was a way to change how it functions from a 'remove suggestions' from the list to a 'highlight the most accurate so far'.  This I BELIEVE would solve some of the lag issues.

Comment: lag issue was mitigated resolved with: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7850#c19

Comment: helios has problems with content assist! downgrade to 3.5 or something

Comment: Hey @Highstead Do you actually want this behaviour, or are you just trying to speed up the incremental filtering of suggestions? If speed is your main concern, I'd humbly recommend waiting for the patch below or temporarily downgrading (in that order), instead of gunning for this (evidently difficult) workaround that may or may not solve your problem. Good luck :)

Comment: @Cheezmeister I would like this functionality, as well as i think it may improve performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem like at this point in time it is possible to duplicate this functionality.  I'll keep an eye on this answer set should anybody choose to prove me wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar question over here:

[How do I defeat Eclipse's autocomplete feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107639/how-do-i-defeat-eclipses-autocomplete-feature)

"There's a bug in Eclipse 3.6.1 that affects code completion (Code Assist). There is supposed to be a patch that will be in 3.6.2 when it's out, but this post from the Android Dev Google group shows a work around that patches 3.6.1. I've tried it and it makes a world of improvement.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/El-6ufT3F7E/uhxmLoUqnQ8J
"

Comment: Just to note.. the official Eclipse 3.6.2 has been released. So far, it does seem to have the fix in place for this and works well.

Answer (score 0):

It's called content assist in Eclipse and you can change almost everything in it.
You find it under Eclipse => Preferences => Java => Editor => Content Assist

Comment: I've played with the settings for some time, and by example if i type 'se' it removes all the functions that do not begin with a 'se'.  My desire is to retain all the functions regardless of if they have it or not, but instead to 'scroll down' to the best fit.