# How do I defeat Eclipse's autocomplete feature?

Tags: android, eclipse

Many times as I am typing a word in android code in Eclipse, my computer freezes for up to 30 seconds while Eclipse trys to find all possible commands to autocomplete my typing. Also, everytime I type a quote charactor " autocomplete types another one that I then have to erase. How do I defeat the autocomplete option that ironically slows me down?

Answer (score 6):

There's a bug in Eclipse 3.6.1 that affects code completion (Code Assist). There is supposed to be a patch that will be in 3.6.2 when it's out, but this post from the Android Dev Google group shows a work around that patches 3.6.1. I've tried it and it makes a world of improvement.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/El-6ufT3F7E/uhxmLoUqnQ8J

Comment: I can vouch for this too. I put the patch in and it fixed the problem.

Comment: That's bad news..it took me a week to get the eclipse/android environment to work. How bad will the update be?

Comment: The update to 3.6.2? I don't know. I do know that I've reinstalled Eclipse a couple of times, and the worse I had to do was reinstall the Android plugin. Not very painful at all. The SDK's you've downloaded and installed should still be there.

Comment: Just to note - the official Eclipse 3.6.2 update has been released. The fix for this issue does seem to be included and it seems to be working well.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem with Eclipse, at least recently.
I struggle with the same though I'm not an Android developer, but I use 3.6.1 which is fairly old.

Options to try include:

- Turn it off completely (not practical, IMHO)
- Filter packages you don't care about (java->appearance->type filters)
- Have less dependencies in your project.
- Turn of Mylyn if you don't use it.
- Make sure you have enough heap space in Eclipse.